# While Loop condition not being met

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, floating-point, greedy

I have this function:

```
int change(float c)
{
    float coins[] = {0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01};
    int count[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    while(c > (0.00))
    {
        printf("I entered here\n");
        if((c-coins[0]) >= (0.00))
        {
            c -= coins[0];
            count[0]++;
            printf("-0.25, c = %.2f\n", c);
        }
        else if((c-coins[1]) >= (0.00))
        {
            c -= coins[1];
            count[1]++;
            printf("-0.10, c = %.2f\n", c);
        }
        else if((c-coins[2]) >= (0.00))
        {
            c -= coins[2];
            count[2]++;
            printf("-0.05, c = %.2f\n", c);
        }
        else if((c-coins[3]) >= (0.00))
        {
            c -= coins[3];
            count[3]++;
            printf("-0.01, c = %.2f\n", c);
        }
    }
    printf("(%d) 25 cents, (%d) 10 cents, (%d) 5 cents, (%d) 1 cents\n",
           count[0], count[1], count[2], count[3]);
    int total = count[0] + count[1] + count[2] + count[3];

    return total;
}
```

And whenever I try to enter 0.06 or 0.07, or any float number that will cause it to reach the last `else if` clause (the `else if((c-coins[3]) >= (0.00))`) it will cause an infinite loop.

Whereas if I enter 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 and their respective perfect multiples, the function goes smoothly. (Because maybe it wont reach the last `else if` clause).

And so when I debugged (using simple `printf` techniques), I found out that the variable `c` *still* enters the `while` loop even though it has reached 0.00. On some occasions, it would even reach -0.00 or -0.01 (and this only works if I changed the `else if((c-coins[3]) >= (0.00))` to `else` only).

Example (assuming the `else if` in the code is already `else` only):
*Input: 0.06*

```
c-0.05, c = 0.01
c-0.01, c = -0.00 **<- WTF** 
(0) 25 cents, (0) 10 cents, (1) 5 cents, (1) 1 cents
Total Coins: 2
```

Someone explain this to me? Am I missing out some rules regarding float numbers here? Or some errors are caused by that last `else if` clause of mine?

*Note*: Changing the last `else if` to `else` may work but can affect the final answer. Also, changing the `while` condition to `-0.00` or `0.001` doesn't work.

Comment: Tangent: don't use floating-point to represent pennies: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Hint: consider what happens for `c = 0.005`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the brackets in `if((c-coins[0]) >= (0.00))` don't contribute to readability (they reduce it). Go for `if(c-coins[0] >= 0)`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: OP is using floating-point to represent dollars. Had he/she been representing pennies, then they could have used an integer. In short, your insinuation is correct, OP should use `int` instead of `float`, the statement itself needs a slight correction...

Comment: @barakmanos: Sure, I guess I intended "don't use float to represent *currency amounts*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point values (typically) use a binary representation. The only fraction in your `coins` array that can be represented *exactly* is `0.25`. All the other values will be slightly smaller or larger than the correct value. This means that every arithmetic operation on these values, even simple substraction, will introduce small computation errors that will cause your comparisons and output to be faulty.

The best solution, in my opinion, is to use only integer types and perform all your calculations in cents (hundreds). You can print out the amounts using division and modulo.

```
int change(int cents)
{
   int coins[] = {25, 10, 5, 1};
   int count[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

   while(cents > 0)
   {
     if((c-coins[0]) >= 0)
     {
        c -= coins[0];
        count[0]++;
        printf("-0.25, c = %d.%02d\n", c/100, c%100);
     }
     /* and so on */
```

You may want to use `unsigned` or `long` or both depending on your needs.